# Should answers influence edits to a question?

Tags: discussion

I have a question from a long time ago when I first joined which references a very specific issue, here:

[Apache not starting in MAMP (but MySQL working) in OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870206/apache-not-starting-in-mamp-but-mysql-working-in-osx)

The title of the question introduces the issue, then in the question body where I describe in detail how I arrived at the problem. *Its not the greatest question on SO by any means.*

None of the answers are anything to do with the things mentioned in the question body such as Postgres, finding the error logs in MAMP etc, but the question likely ranks well in Google for the title and has been viewed thousands of times.

Should you edit a question like this based on the answers to be more relevant?
Should I just leave it well alone?

Another point to make is that my answer on the question has being down voted a couple of times, but is technically the only relevant answer. I don't mind that at all, it is probably an awful answer but it exemplifies the fact that perhaps I should edit the question and remove my answer.